# To prove (KB ⊭ S) and (KB ⊭ ¬S) is satisfiable

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

[image]

In question (e), I have to prove: A ≡ (KB ⊭ S) and (KB ⊭ ¬S) is satisfiable, where KB and S are propositional variables. I am not able to follow the solution given in the image above as to why it is replacing S with another propositional variable P. Even if we do take P, one of (KB ⊭ P) and (KB ⊭ ¬P) becomes true and other false making A as false. So anyway here's what I tried, I find some interpretation to make statement A false, if I cannot find such interpretation then A is a tautology. From what I understand, (KB ⊭ S) is true (i.e. KB does not entail S is true) when premise KB is true and the consequence S is false. So if I take KB ≡ TRUE and S ≡ TRUE making (KB ⊭ S) ≡ FALSE making A ≡ FALSE, hence A is not a tautology, whereas the answer given in above image is Yes.

Comment: So I read the question wrong. It was to prove the statement in question was satisfiable by some interpretation and that's what the selected answer proves. Right? @MohammadRostami. So I am editing the question.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  Don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say $\alpha\models KB$, this means that $models(\alpha)\subseteq models(KB)$ that $models$ of $\alpha$ is used for
an assignment that evaluates  formula $\phi$ to true.

Under above interpretation, suppose $KB\equiv True$, and $S$ be  a formula that isn't Tautology and just satisfiable (i.e. $A\vee B$), in propositional logic, hence we can conclude that

$$True\nvDash    S\wedge True\nvDash     \neg S.$$

Because $$models(KB)\nsubseteq  models(S)\wedge models(KB)\nsubseteq  models(\neg S).$$